# How can I tail a log with notepad++ without samba?

Tags: samba, sftp

I wish to tail a large log file. I used to access the file through samba but IT don't agree to install samba on the servers. We have sFTP but I can only download the log file and then view it. However, I want to read it as it grows in realtime, like using `tail -f` on a *nix machine.

Is there a plugin for notepad++ that I can use in order to view the log in such a way?

Comment: Can't you ssh and `tail` directly it? You can `tail -n NN > newlog.txt` and then copy and open the new shorter one with Notepad++ (but why Notepad++?)

Comment: I have the same problem, i have notepad++ 7.8.3 and tail dont works in realtime, i can see the file with NPPftp, but not in realtime, i have to download it each time. Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Install the Document Monitor Plugin in Notepad++.

1. Open Notepad++.
2. Click Plugins, click *Plugin Manager*, click *Show Plugin Manager*.
3. Click the checkbox next to *Document Monitor*, then click *Install* (let it restart Notepad++ when prompted).
4. With Notepad++ open, open the log file to be monitored.
5. Click *Plugins*, click *Document Monitor*, click *Start to Monitor*.
6. The file will automatically be reloaded when it is updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the last version (7.5.6) the tail -f function should works.
[image]